# How to override Contains property of a list in C#?

Tags: c#, list, overriding, contains, gethashcode

I have a list of an object `List<IReportRelationMapping>` that I need to check if the list does not contain a specific `ReportRelationMapping` object

Here is how my `ReportRelationMapping` looks like

```
public class ReportRelationMapping : IReportRelationMapping
{
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public IReportRelation LocalRelation { get; set; }

     public IReportRelation ForeignRelation { get; set; }

     public IReportRelationMapping RelatedThrough { get; set; }
}
```

The list contains an object if `this.LocalRelation == passed.LocalRelation &&  this.ForeignRelation == passed.ForeignRelation` or `this.LocalRelation == passed.ForeignRelation &&  this.ForeignRelation == passed.LocalRelation`

Here is what I have done in order to override the `Contains` property of the list

```
public class ReportRelationMapping : IReportRelationMapping
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IReportRelation LocalRelation { get; set; }

    public IReportRelation ForeignRelation { get; set; }

    public IReportRelationMapping RelatedThrough { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(ReportRelationMapping other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.GetType() != other.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return (this.LocalRelation == other.LocalRelation && this.ForeignRelation == other.ForeignRelation)
            || (this.LocalRelation == other.ForeignRelation && this.ForeignRelation == other.LocalRelation);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.GetType() != other.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.Equals(other as ReportRelationMapping);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 14;
        hash = (hash * 7) + this.ForeignRelation.GetHashCode();
        return (hash * 7) + this.LocalRelation.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ReportRelationMapping lhs, ReportRelationMapping rhs)
    {
        // Check for null on left side. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null))
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null))
            {
                // null == null = true. 
                return true;
            }

            // Only the left side is null. 
            return false;
        }
        // Equals handles case of null on right side. 
        return lhs.Equals(rhs);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ReportRelationMapping lhs, ReportRelationMapping rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }

}
```

But for some reason even when the list contains a giving object I get `false` or "does not contains the object."  When I debug my code, I can see that the the debugger reaches the `Equal` method so it goes through my code but it never reach `GetHashCode` method. I am not sure if I am implementing my `GetHashCode` method incorrectly here.

What did I miss here? Why Contains always return "Not Contain" in my case?
How can I correctly override this `Contains` method of a list?

Comment: Well your hash code doesn't match with the Equals as it should return the same thing for two objects that are equal.  The hash should be something more like `return this.ForeignRelation.GetHashCode() + this.LocalRelation.GetHashCode();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should do this by calling [Enumerable.Any()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx), like this:

```
bool contains = myList.Any(t =>
    (t.LocalRelation == passed.LocalRelation && t.ForeignRelation == passed.ForeignRelation)
    || (t.LocalRelation == passed.ForeignRelation && t.ForeignRelation == passed.LocalRelation)
```

No need to override `Equals` or any of that.

Or, if you don't want to use `Enumerable` (LINQ), there's the [List.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx) method, which you call in the same way:

```
bool contains = myList.Exists(t =>
    (t.LocalRelation == passed.LocalRelation && t.ForeignRelation == passed.ForeignRelation)
    || (t.LocalRelation == passed.ForeignRelation && t.ForeignRelation == passed.LocalRelation)
```

Comment: This is still giving me the same results. It is always does not exists even though it exists

Comment: @Jaylen: Then there's something you're not telling us. You need to provide us with a specific example that we can test. Probably you should pare down your objects to be as simple as possible so that you don't kill us with code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for details.

Comment: Actually I told you the true story but for some reason `.Any()` did not work for me from the first try. Now it did. I think I missed something. Thank you very much for your help with this. Would there be a reason to chose one way over the other? are they identical?

Comment: @Jaylen: The nice thing about `Enumerable.Any()` is that it will work with any class that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which includes all of the collections in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, as well as arrays and most custom collections that people have created that support LINQ. `List.Exists` only works with `LIst<T>`. It's *possible* that `List.Exists()` is faster if it doesn't use an enumerator, so that's something you'd want to check out if your application is hugely performance sensitive.